# Error Message for Hyper-V and Data Execution for Docker-Desktop on Windows 10 Failing to Start

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-swarm

So when I installed Docker Desktop on Windows 1909 and an Insiders Version and am getting this issue. Furthermore, I have Hyper-V enabled and Data Execution Protection enabled. I also checked the Windows settings in the Programs and Features. I have also made a GitHub issue as well.

```
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
----------------------------------------
Windows.Data
    Assembly Version: 255.255.255.255
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10011.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Data.winmd
----------------------------------------
System.ValueTuple
    Assembly Version: 4.0.3.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26515.06
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.ValueTuple.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Collections
    Assembly Version: 4.0.11.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Collections.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.Win32Helpers
    Assembly Version: 1.0.7257.10303
    Win32 Version: 
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.Win32Helpers.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26011.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Net.Http.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Management.Automation
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.19041.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management.Automation/v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Management.Automation.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Resources.ResourceManager
    Assembly Version: 4.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.25714.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Resources.ResourceManager.DLL
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsIntegration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsFormsIntegration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Http
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Web.Http.DLL
----------------------------------------
Docker.HttpApi
    Assembly Version: 2.1.0.40693
    Win32 Version: 2.1.0.40693
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Docker.HttpApi.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Owin
    Assembly Version: 4.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.80118.116
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
Owin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.NamedPipe
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.NamedPipe.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.Server.Owin
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.Server.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.80118.116
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.DLL
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Http.Owin
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Web.Http.Owin.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Net.Http.Formatting
    Assembly Version: 5.2.7.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.61128.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Net.Http.Formatting.DLL
----------------------------------------
SMDiagnostics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/SMDiagnostics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/SMDiagnostics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.26606.05
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
HttpOverStream.Client
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/HttpOverStream.Client.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I am curious if there is something I can do to fix the exception. 
Also, before the update I could get both Virtualbox VMs and Docker to work side-by-side using Hyper-V as the hypervisor for my Linux boxes. I have checked to see if it was enabled in the BIOS and within the services on Windows SCM and it was definitely enabled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Github Issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6689

Expected behavior
I have two versions of Windows both with Insiders Builds. One has a functional Docker and I can run both Linux and Windows Containers just fine. However, after the recent update and the enable-ment of WSL 2 I am seeing that one of my machines is no longer functional with Docker Desktop. I would expect to be able to restart my computer and the docker daemon would start. Furthermore, I would expect that Re-installing it would work as well. I have checked both my BIOS and Have installed Hyper-V and have followed through all of the troubleshooting advice possible.

Actual behavior
Prior to the update, I used to have a functional working Docker Desktop and now it no longer works, which is causing havoc for development workflows.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed this by enabling hyper-v from cmdlet.

I visited this site, and the solution posted here worked for me. 
https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/11/16/installing-hyperv-module-for-powershell.aspx

Furthermore, I have noticed that an issue is also occurring within `WSL 2` on the newest update. Try the following if Docker-Desktop is not working on startup and just stays in a for-loop initializing:

Enter The following commands within an elevated command prompt:

1. Enable Hyper V - You can do this by running the following command as administrator.

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

2. Enable Hypervisor with following command.

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Research: https://dotnetthoughts.net/hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-protection-must-be-enabled/

Then Restart and prompt asks to download the Linux Kernel

Apparently Docker Desktop is forgetting this in their initial set-up for the updates and installation for anybody using Hyper-V and the Linux Containers requiring the WSL2 Linux Kernel Backend to initialize Containers. provided by Microsoft.

Microsoft Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel

Download the above ^^

Answer (score 0):

In a Response to the recent Docker Desktop Issues for People Updating to the Newest Broke Version, here is what worked for me (I downloaded from the Website after uninstalling and disabling Hyper-V Module and then reproduced it again under the chocolatey version):

## Windows

Here is what worked for me:
If you want to do it on Windows I would do the following:
1. Uninstall Everything Related to Docker-Desktop in Control Panel and disable Hyper-V
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v
2. If you are using Chocolatey you can uninstall all of that there too with `choco uninstall package` and disable Hyper-V https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v
3. Restart your Machine and Enter BIOS Menu and Make sure you have Virtualization and/or Hyperthreading Enabled.

Use this link to see how to get into BIOS: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500006
You may need to reset your BIOS to default (Note not all Machines Support Virtualization) 
4. Allow for normal boot to occur
5. Enable Hyper-V for Windows 10 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v
6. Run through the following in an elevated command prompt and allowing for administrative access by right-clicking on command prompt:

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

7. Restart Your Computer One More Time
8. Boot up
9. You can go to Docker-Desktop or you can install it with Chocolatey
   If you want to install it via website, I assume you know where to go. Get the Stable Version. 
   10 (Option A). Install as normal via https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop
   10 (Option B). Use Chocolatey: 
   Open up powershell in elevated admin console and install chocolatey

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

https://chocolatey.org/install

Then after you install it run:

```
choco install docker-desktop
```

Chocolatey Link: https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-desktop#releasenotes
Docker Release Notes: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/

Whatever you decide, you need to make sure 
1. Your System Supports Virtualization
2. You have that enabled in System BIOS
3. Makes sure you have downloaded the WSL 2 background: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel

Hope this helps, I too have had so many problems with Docker-Desktop as of late.